# MongoDB/Mongoose whats the best way to count a lot of documents with a filter?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, backend

I understand that `estimatedDocumentCount()` uses metadata to count, which makes it faster when there are a lot of documents. But the drawback is that you cant add a filter on it like `countDocuments()`. What if there are still a lot of documents, but you want to use a filter, what's the best way to do that, if there is a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you got it right.

`countDocuments(...)` is how you count documents with a filter.

If you're facing issues with speed, I'd advise you to add [an index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/) on the fields you're planning to filter with, this way it's an index scan and the result will be almost immediate.

Answer (score 0):

It would follow that you are filtering based on the contents of the document, and that you would not be able to do so only with metadata.

You could add an index, or insert your data into an exclusive collection using normalized data models.

The documentation also [suggests](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#db.collection.count) that you could create a view and count based on the metadata.